# Would like a way to improve my my SQL query in ASP

Tags: sql, asp-classic

I would simply like to get the latest record from the Division_Program column. 
The data within the "JMSDay" column data are populated with the seven days of the week. I used an array to abbreviate the days (i.e. Mon thru Sun). the "JMS_UpdateTime" column data uses the following format 8/4/2013 1:02:12 PM

```
SELECT top 1 * 
FROM CensusFacility_Records 
WHERE JMSDay = '" & smDateArray (Weekday(date)) & "' 
AND Division_Program ='" & divrec &"' 
order by JMS_UpdateDateTime desc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH Census AS
(
    SELECT
     *
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY JMS_UpdateDateTime DESC) AS RowID
    FROM CensusFacility_Records
    WHERE JMSDay = '" & smDateArray (Weekday(date)) & "' 
    AND Division_Program ='" & divrec &"' 
)
SELECT * FROM Census
WHERE RowID=1;
```